# URL to image as displayed by browser

Tags: java, ui-automation

I'm automating our organization's supply ordering system. Under the current (paper) system, we need to attach a printout of the web page displaying the requested item if we're ordering off of a web site.  The system I'm writing has a method to upload scanned documents, but I'd like to make it one-click operation instead of printing the web page, scanning it, then uploading the file of the scan.

I found [this](http://searchdomino.techtarget.com/tip/Converting-Web-pages-to-images-using-Java) code to convert the page into an image, and it *does* work, but the image created is based off of the html (which makes sense), but not what is displayed in browser.

For example, I'm viewing this item:

[image: Sample Amazon item]

---

When I run the url through the code, this is the returned image:

[image: Returned image]

The project is Java web using a servlet.  The servlet code:

```
    try {
        if (request.getParameter("formType").equalsIgnoreCase("addReference")) {
            String url = request.getParameter("url");
            BufferedImage bi = WebImage.create(url, 800, 600);
            File tmpFile = new File("c:/testimages/url2img.png");
            ImageIO.write(bi, "png", tmpFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The code from the link above:

```
public abstract class WebImage {
    static class Kit extends HTMLEditorKit {
        @Override
        public Document createDefaultDocument() {
            HTMLDocument doc
                    = (HTMLDocument) super.createDefaultDocument();
            doc.setTokenThreshold(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            doc.setAsynchronousLoadPriority(-1);
            return doc;
        }
    }
    public static BufferedImage create(String src, int width, int height) {
        BufferedImage image = null;
        JEditorPane pane = new JEditorPane();
        Kit kit = new Kit();
        pane.setEditorKit(kit);
        pane.setEditable(false);
        pane.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        try {
            pane.setPage(src);
            image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics g = image.createGraphics();
            Container c = new Container();
            SwingUtilities.paintComponent(g, pane, c, 0, 0, width, height);
            g.dispose();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return image;
    }
}
```

Is there any way to return an image of the url **as displayed by the browser**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Java, so there's actually a really simple solution. Browser automation is a (mostly) solved problem with [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Here is some sample code, just note that it's not particularly robust if the page takes longer than usual to load but it should suffice to demonstrate the steps necessary to do what you want. Also note, that if this needs to run headlessly you might want to look into [JBrowserDriver](https://github.com/MachinePublishers/jBrowserDriver) instead of the FireFox driver.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.amazon.com/I-Robot-Isaac-Asimov/dp/055338256X/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1496161782&sr=8-2&keywords=Asimov");
// This move is necessary, the original file is temporary and gets deleted after java exists
File resultingScreenshot = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "screenshot.png");
Files.move(screenshotFile, resultingScreenshot);
driver.quit();

System.out.println("The screenshot is found here: " + resultingScreenshot);
```

Comment: While I'm sure your answer is valid, I can't get it to work on my project.  Plus, it seems like I'm adding a lot to the project (ie, Selenium) that is unnecessary -- kind of like using a whole car when all I need is the left turn signal bulb.  But, thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're importing the library, but I recommend using maven to manage your dependencies. It'll simplify creating your classpath and running this code. [Here it is on github](https://github.com/paul-nelson-baker/selenium-screenshot-demo). As far as adding a lot, it's somewhat mandatory for your problem. You'll either re-invent the wheel and build a java capable javascript engine and browser (which you'll have to maintain yourself, which can be fun and academic but time consuming) or you use an already active project. You just have to pick and choose what is best for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need a fully fledged browser with all of its support for tonnes of web standards (HTML, CSS, JS) in order to achieve what you want. Otherwise you will often be capturing badly rendered images by a substandard web browser.

Have a look at Selenium as suggested by [BCqrstoO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1478636/bcqrstoo).

Additionally there are also  [Headless Chrome](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md) which comes with Chrome 59 (yet to come for Windows)
or [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) which unfortunately is no longer maintained, and therefore the ability to render latest and greatest pages will diminish over time.